# extract a passenger version from gem list command

Tags: ruby, regex, rubygems

How to extract passenger version in separate variable in ruby code

`pasver = %x[/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem list  | grep passenger | sed -r 's/(passenger ()(.*)())/\2/]`

UPDATE:::

My Solution:

```
pasver = `/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem list | grep passenger`.sub /.*\((.*)\).*/, '\1'
```

Comment: in what string you searching

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of gemspecs from within Ruby, from which you can easily extract version numbers:

```
Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name("passenger").map(&:version).map(&:to_s)
```

Comment: This is not useful for me because I am using chef to install rvm in /usr/local/rvm instead of default ruby interpreter. I would like to see more regexp instead of any other. I don't know. And i need a version of gem installed from gem bin: /usr/local/rvm/bin/gem binary. Therefore I use sed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex:

```
passenger *\(([^)]+?)\)
```

Will take everything what is in parentheses